# How to handle synchronous errors with async await?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await, try-catch, generator

I've been getting some unhandled rejections in my app, but I was pretty certain that all of my code is correctly wrapped with error handling. After digging around I found that async/await is not behaving as I expected. Basically my async function throws a sync error and that error is then getting treated as an uncaught exception. This happens even when I wrap my code in a try catch explicitly, but not when I await a sync method which throws an error.

So here's my test code:

```
function test() {
  async function one() {
    try {
      await three();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('caught', new Error().stack);
      return error;
    }
  }
  async function three() {
    try {
      throw new Error();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('caught', new Error().stack);
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }

  one().then(function (result) {
    console.log({result});
  }).catch(error => console.log({ error }));
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) => console.log('not caught', e.stack));

test();
```

Here's the output I see in the console:

```
not caught Error
    at three$ (imports/access-control/execute-handler.js:25:13)
    at tryCatch (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:299:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at tryCatch (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at invoke (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:155:20)
    at /Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:198:11
    at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:197:16)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:220:13)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
caught Error
    at one$ (imports/access-control/execute-handler.js:11:29)
    at tryCatch (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:299:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at tryCatch (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at invoke (/Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:155:20)
    at /Users/joshuaohlman/Development/Xolvio/xspecs/modules/web-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:167:13
    at /Users/joshuaohlman/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.8.9.ghfed++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39
{ result: [Error] }
(STDERR) [Error] [Function]
```

**So my question is, is this expected behavior?**

If so, how can I nicely wrap my async functions so that they catch both synchronous and asynchronous errors in a way that allows me to handle them my self or pass them on as rejections.

I'm using babel to compile my code (this particular bit of code runs in node though I also run my code in the browser).

If it's interesting, here's the compiled version of my code:

```
                                                                                                              //
function test() {                                                                                                      // 6
  function one() {                                                                                                     // 7
    return _regenerator2.default.async(function () {                                                                   // 7
      function one$(_context) {                                                                                        // 7
        while (1) {                                                                                                    // 7
          switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {                                                                     // 7
            case 0:                                                                                                    // 7
              _context.prev = 0;                                                                                       // 7
              _context.next = 3;                                                                                       // 7
              return _regenerator2.default.awrap(three());                                                             // 7
                                                                                                                      //
            case 3:                                                                                                    // 7
              _context.next = 9;                                                                                       // 7
              break;                                                                                                   // 7
                                                                                                                      //
            case 5:                                                                                                    // 7
              _context.prev = 5;                                                                                       // 7
              _context.t0 = _context["catch"](0);                                                                      // 7
              console.log('caught', new Error().stack);                                                                // 11
              return _context.abrupt("return", _context.t0);                                                           // 7
                                                                                                                      //
            case 9:                                                                                                    // 7
            case "end":                                                                                                // 7
              return _context.stop();                                                                                  // 7
          }                                                                                                            // 7
        }                                                                                                              // 7
      }                                                                                                                // 7
                                                                                                                      //
      return one$;                                                                                                     // 7
    }(), null, this, [[0, 5]]);                                                                                        // 7
  }                                                                                                                    // 7
                                                                                                                      //
  function two() {                                                                                                     // 15
    return _regenerator2.default.async(function () {                                                                   // 15
      function two$(_context2) {                                                                                       // 15
        while (1) {                                                                                                    // 15
          switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {                                                                   // 15
            case 0:                                                                                                    // 15
              _context2.prev = 0;                                                                                      // 15
              _context2.next = 3;                                                                                      // 15
              return _regenerator2.default.awrap(three());                                                             // 15
                                                                                                                      //
            case 3:                                                                                                    // 15
              _context2.next = 9;                                                                                      // 15
              break;                                                                                                   // 15
                                                                                                                      //
            case 5:                                                                                                    // 15
              _context2.prev = 5;                                                                                      // 15
              _context2.t0 = _context2["catch"](0);                                                                    // 15
              console.log('caught', new Error().stack);                                                                // 19
              return _context2.abrupt("return", _context2.t0);                                                         // 15
                                                                                                                      //
            case 9:                                                                                                    // 15
            case "end":                                                                                                // 15
              return _context2.stop();                                                                                 // 15
          }                                                                                                            // 15
        }                                                                                                              // 15
      }                                                                                                                // 15
                                                                                                                      //
      return two$;                                                                                                     // 15
    }(), null, this, [[0, 5]]);                                                                                        // 15
  }                                                                                                                    // 15
                                                                                                                      //
  function three() {                                                                                                   // 23
    return _regenerator2.default.async(function () {                                                                   // 23
      function three$(_context3) {                                                                                     // 23
        while (1) {                                                                                                    // 23
          switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next) {                                                                   // 23
            case 0:                                                                                                    // 23
              _context3.prev = 0;                                                                                      // 23
              throw new Error();                                                                                       // 23
                                                                                                                      //
            case 4:                                                                                                    // 23
              _context3.prev = 4;                                                                                      // 23
              _context3.t0 = _context3["catch"](0);                                                                    // 23
              console.log('caught', new Error().stack);                                                                // 27
              return _context3.abrupt("return", Promise.reject(_context3.t0));                                         // 23
                                                                                                                      //
            case 8:                                                                                                    // 23
            case "end":                                                                                                // 23
              return _context3.stop();                                                                                 // 23
          }                                                                                                            // 23
        }                                                                                                              // 23
      }                                                                                                                // 23
                                                                                                                      //
      return three$;                                                                                                   // 23
    }(), null, this, [[0, 4]]);                                                                                        // 23
  }                                                                                                                    // 23
                                                                                                                      //
  one().then(function (result) {                                                                                       // 32
    console.log({                                                                                                      // 33
      result: result                                                                                                   // 33
    });                                                                                                                // 33
  }).catch(function (error) {                                                                                          // 34
    return console.log({                                                                                               // 34
      error: error                                                                                                     // 34
    });                                                                                                                // 34
  });                                                                                                                  // 34
}                                                                                                                      // 35
                                                                                                                      //
process.on('unhandledRejection', function (e) {                                                                        // 37
  return console.log('not caught', e.stack);                                                                           // 37
});                                                                                                                    // 37
test();
```

**Update**

I can't reproduce this issue using the latest version of regenerator so assuming this is a bug in my version of regenerator or babel or something related to my environment.

**Update**

Lance Whatley points out that it's incorrect to return a promise from an async function, I'm not sure if that's the case, however the behavior that I'm definitely not expecting is that the console log statement inside of the `three()` catch clause is never called.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `three()` async function. Instead of `return Promise.reject(e)` in your catch block, you can either not use a try/catch in the three function, and let any calling method handle errors, or if you must use try/catch in `three()` (for example, if you want to log the output as it appears you're currently doing before throwing the error to the calling function), throw the same exception again after logging.

An example of redefining `three()` to behave this way would be the following, which only changes the last line in your catch block:

```
// Rejects this async function, so the calling function will act as if the promise was rejected
async function three() {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('caught', new Error().stack);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

or

```
// Defines a function that returns a promise that's instantly rejected, so your calling method can handle the rejection
async function three() {
  throw new Error()
}
```

The last `throw e;` effectively rejects the promise in your calling function which behaves as expected. Running `return Promise.reject(e)` does NOT reject the calling async function, but instead returns a Promise rejection object as if it's resolved in your parent function.

Comment: Interesting, I think you're right about the problem currently, although I originally tested this code without the try catch (e.g. just throwing the error). However, even with that caveate, it's important to note that the catch clause is never called, notice that the output never includes a second 'catch' console log.

Comment: On second thought, doesn't returning a promise from a promise just unwrap the promise? So returning a promise shouldn't make any difference, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug and updating my package versions fixed it. I'll leave this question an answer up since it took me an amazingly long time to discover the issue and fix it and there's a lot of confusion surrounding the correct behavior of async/await with try/catch blocks.